# How do I write a multi-regex line?

Tags: java, regex, validation

I'm trying to write a line of regex that performs the following:

A string variable that can contain only:

- The letters a to z (upper and lowercase) (zero or many times)
- The hyphen character (zero or many times)
- The single quote character (zero or one time)
- The space character (zero or one time)

Tried searching through many regex websites

```
.matches("([a-zA-Z_0-9']*(\\s)?)(-)?"))
```

This allows close to what I want, however you cant start typing a-z anymore after you have typed in space character. So it's sequential in a way. I want the validation to allow for any sequence of those factors.

Expected:
Allowed to type a string that has any amount of a-zA-Z, zero to one space, zero to one dash, anywhere throughout the string.

Comment: Regex is not a good way to solve this problem. Was that part of the homework definition? If not, the point was clearly NOT to use regex for this.

Comment: @rzwitserloot It is simply the name (string) can only contain those characters defined above.

Comment: @Emma It can only contain the space or dash once or zero times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a validation for that

`"^(?!.*\\s.*\\s)(?!.*'.*')[a-zA-Z'\\s-]*$"`

Expanded

```
 ^                      # Begin
 (?! .* \s .* \s )      # Max single whitespace
 (?! .* ' .* ' )        # Max single, single quote
 [a-zA-Z'\s-]*          # Optional a-z, A-Z, ', whitespace or - characters
 $                      # End
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess,

```
^(?!.*([ ']).*\\1)[A-Za-z' -]*$
```

might work OK.

---

Here,

```
(?!.*([ ']).*\\1)
```

we are trying to say that, if there was horizontal space (\h) or single quote (') twice in the string, exclude those, which we would be then keeping only those with zero or one time of repetition.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "^(?!.*([ ']).*\\1)[A-Za-z' -]*$";
        final String string = "abcAbc- ";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: abcAbc- 
Group 1: null
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/JH37pI/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/JH37pI/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: It can only contain the space or dash once or zero times

Comment: `\s` is not "space character", it matches a "whitespace character", and "whitespace" is more than just the "space" character, it also matches `\t`, `\n`, `\x0B`, `\f`, and `\r`, and I doubt that those should be allowed.